# Load a SWF inside another SWF

Tags: flash

How can I load a SWF inside another SWF? I found a few links, tried to do as explained, but when I load the page the embedded SWF is bigger than it was supposed to be and is not aligned well.

PS: I managed to resize the embedded SWF, as you can see.

[This is the test page](http://rigo.ro/test/galerie.html) and here are the links that I found:

1. [Embed Swf In Swf](http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/862718)
2. [What is the script to play SWF within an SWF](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=657461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found this one [Insert SWF into FLA](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=286640) from [kirupa.com](http://www.kirupa.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AS3: have you tried using the [`Loader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Loader.html) class in the `flash.display` package?